# Searching a column for a set of values and listing missing values

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2013

I have a column of 45 spaces that will have letters and numbers. I want to write a formula that will search the column for the values 1-10 and list the values found more than once or not found. I haven't been able to find a way to use existing formulas to do this.
i.e. Given the following column...

```
1
3
6
2
8
7
8
10
```

result [4,5,8,9]

Answer (score 1):

Use this formula:

`=IFERROR(SMALL(IF(COUNTIF(SourceRange,ROW($1:$10))=1,"",ROW($1:$10)),ROW()),"")`

- `COUNTIF(SourceRange,ROW($1:$10))` - check the number of occurrences of numbers 1-10 in the source range (named range in the formula
- `IF(COUNTIF(...)=1,"",ROW($1:$10))` - creates a list for numbers 1-10, the list contains empty string for numbers occurring once in the range, and contains the number itself for all the other cases (not occurring or more then once)
- `SMALL(IF(...),ROW())` - enter the numbers from the list into a column
- `=IFERROR(SMALL(...),"")` - fills the range after values with blanks instead of errors

Put this formula in any column, starting from first row, fill down at least for ten rows to get correct result in case all numbers need to be displayed.

This is an array formula, you need to enter it with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>.

[image]

Comment: does not working...

Comment: @JustMe: How exactly it doesn't work?

Comment: nothing happens after I introduce formula , see this print screen https://snag.gy/V6igaD.jpg

Comment: Have you defined `SourceRange`? Also seems your input numbers are actually stored as text.

Comment: can you please Upload somewhere the files and share it here? Because I don't know exactly what settings should I make. I don;t know excel too good :(